# How to serialize property to json in nlog

Tags: c#, json, nlog

I have following configuration:

```
<target>
<layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
 <attribute name="Foo" layout="${event-properties:item=Foo:@}" />
</layout>
</target>
```

This is the resulting doc pushed to output:

```
{
   "Foo": "{ \"Nested\": \"Json\" } "
}
```

Instead I would like following result:

```
{
   "Foo": {  "Nested": "Json" }
}
```

However I want to render just `Foo` property as json, not all event-properties. Nested json layout does not have source. How to get around that?

Answer (score 0):

[NLog JsonLayout](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/JsonLayout) will automatically fix the output coming from attribute-Layout, so reserved characters becomes escaped correctly.

But if you already know the output will be valid json (happens when using `format=@`), then you can specify `encode="false"` like this:

```xml
<target>
 <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
   <attribute name="Foo" layout="${event-properties:item=Foo:format=@}" encode="false" />
 </layout>
</target>
```